# Perl: Trying to see if the Nth column of line X matches the Nth column of line X-1

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl script that reads text file line by line and splits the line into 4 different columns (shown by dashes & referred to as $cols[0-3] in code; important parts are bolded). For each distinct value *before* the decimal point in column 0, it should randomly generate a hex color.

Essentially, I need to compare if the Xth column in the current line matches that of the previous line.

A----last_column----221----18

A----last_column----221----76

A----last_column----221----42

B----last_column----335----18

C----last_column----467----83

So far, I am randomly generating a new #random_hex_color for every line, but desired output is below:

**221**.18-------**#EB23AE1**-------**@$some/random/path/A.txt**-------last_column

**221**.76-------**#EB23AE1**-------**@$some/random/path/A.txt**-------last_column

**221**.42-------**#EB23AE1**-------**@$some/random/path/A.txt**-------last_column

**335**.18-------**#AC16D6E**-------**@$some/random/path/B.txt**-------last_column

**467**.83-------**#FD89A1C**-------**@$some/random/path/C.txt**-------last_column

[Image of input file and desired output][1]

```
my @cols;
my $row;
my $color = color_gen();
my $path = "\t@\some_random_path/"; 
my $newvar = dir_contents();
my @array = ($color, $path, $newvar);
my %hash;

while ($row = <$fh>){
    next if $row =~ /^(#|\s|\t)/; #skip lines beginning with comments and spaces
    @cols = split(" ", $row);
    %hash = (
        "$cols[2]" => ["$color", "$path", "$newvar"]
         );
    say Dumper (\%hash);
    print("$cols[2].$cols[3]\t#");
    print(color_gen());
    printf("%-65s", $path.dir_contents());
    print("\t\t$cols[0]_"."$cols[1]"." 1 1\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Cori! If you have a moment, please visit our [help] and visit the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash to store, and thus be able to check for, the distinct values in the first column.

I assume that `color_gen()` returns a new random color at each invocation. The desired output is unclear to me so it is only indicated in the code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not $file or not -f $file;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my %c0;

while (<$fh>) {
    next if /^(?:\s*$|\s*#)/;  # skip: spaces only or empty, comment
    my @cols = split;

    my ($num) = $cols[0] =~ /^([0-9]+)/;

    if (not exists $c0{$num}) {  # this number not seen yet; assign color
        $c0{$num} = color_gen();
    }

    # write line of output, with $c0{$num} and @cols
}
```

The value "*before the decimal point in column 0*" is extracted using regex as the leading number in that string and stored in `$num`. The parens around are needed to provide the list context for the match operator, in which case it returns the captured values. See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

This number is stored as a key in a hash with its value being the generated color. Unless it already exists that is, in which case it has been seen and a color for it generated. This way you can keep track of distinct numbers in that column. Then you can write output using `$c0{$num}`.

This can be written far more compactly but I hoped for clarity.

The skipped lines here aren't those "*beginning with comments and spaces*" but are ones with only spaces (or empty), or comments. If you really mean to skip lines that merely start with whitespace (or `#`) then indeed use `/^(?:\s|#)/`, where `?:` makes `()` only group and not capture.

A few comments on the code

- Always have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning of each program
- The `\s` in regex matches most types of whitespace; no need for a separate pattern for tab
- A variable can be declared right in the `while` condition, which makes it perfectly scoped -- to that loop. However, you can also omit it and use `$_`
- If `while` condition has only the input read, such as `<$fh>`, then the value is assigned to [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_); also see [I/O in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).
  I use that here since then the regex is simpler (match on `$_` by default) and so is `split`
- The [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) without arguments has default of `split ' ', $_;`, where `' '` stands for any amount of any whitespace (and leading spaces are removed before splitting)

Please provide exact samples of input and desired output for a more complete example.

Comment: With your suggestions an some playing around, I've gotten it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CoriGrainger  Great :)  If any questions come up please let me know.